# Bash - assign results to value

Tags: bash, shell

I have a additionaly script **help_script.sh**:

```
....
result="example"
```

and the 
**main.bash**

```
var=`sh help_script.sh`
echo $var
```

Is there any way to assign the result from help_script.sh to the var value in the main.sh? I know solution with "echo", but I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: Why are you looking for another solution?

Comment: in the main script I use also commmand 'echo ...'

Answer (score 1):

Use the `source` keyword to inline the `help_script.sh`

This will run the script in the same context so any variables should remain in scope.

See this Super User question for more details https://superuser.com/q/46139/149483

Comment: I had `source` keyword in the `help_script.sh`. I would like use the `help_script.sh` script like a function, so I looking for a solution to assign the  funtions/scripts result to value in another script.

Comment: Define proper Bash functions and then source the script to include the functions

Comment: OK and how can I assign the functions results (without echo command)? This is my problem.